# flutter error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?

Tags: flutter, dart

I´m trying to acess the score of a given question:

```
 main() {
      final questions = const [
        {
          "question": "Your favorite animal?",
          "answer": [
            {"text": "Lion", "score": 4},
            {"text": "Tiger", "score": 6},
          ]
        }
      ];
    
      print(questions[0]["answer"]["score"]);
    }
```

Here´s how i´m trying to acess it: print(questions[0]["answer"]["score"]);

But it´s showing me an error:

```
Error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.
  print(questions[0]["answer"]["pontuacao"]);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `questions[0]["answer"]` gives you a list of elements, you need to index into it before calling `["score"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until `questions[0]["answer"]` it's ok. But then, that returns an array, in particular:

```
[
  {"text": "Lion", "score": 4},
  {"text": "Tiger", "score": 6},
]
```

So, if you want to print a single score, just add an index like `questions[0]["answer"][0]["score"]`.
Otherwise, if you want to print them all, just use

```
questions[0]["answer"].map((element) => print(element["score"])
```

If you want to print ALL questions's scores, do te same for questions array:

```
questions.map((question) => question["answer"].map((element) => print(element["score"]))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question, this is exactly what i needed.